# Send checkbox values in Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

The following code is my original code. In the code, I tried to post value of an input for each checkbox which is checked.

```
      <tbody class="myFormSaldo">
          <tr>
            <td> <input name="checkbox['.$i.']" type="checkbox" value="'.$i.'" id="chb'.$ref.'" onchange="enableList(this);" class="chb_group" /> </td>

            <td> <input name="items['.$i.']" type="text" readonly value="'.$obj->items.'" /> </td>

            <td> <input name="size['.$i.']" type="text" readonly value="'.$obj->size.'Kg" /> </td>

            <td> <input name="quantity['.$i.']"  type="text" readonly value="'.$obj->myquantity.'" /> </td>



        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $i) {

                            $product_name=$_POST['items'][$i];
                            $product_size=$_POST['size'][$i];
```

The code above is working fine. It post the value of each inputs for each checkbox which were checked. For example; if there were three checkedbox which were checked and the form was submited, then it would post three arrays (3 loop) of : $product_name,$product_size,etc..

What I want now is to use Ajax. Like this:

```
    var product_name= document.getElementById('product_name').value;
    var product_size = document.getElementById('product_size').value;
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "../actions/selectReferenceOrder.php",
        data: product_name='+product_name+'&product_size ='+product_size ,
        cache: false,
        success:function(html)
        {
            document.getElementById('outputReference').innerHTML = html;
        }
    });
```

But it doesn't count or find the checkbox

So my question now is how to do the same as the php do with `foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $i)` in ajax?

I am just a beginner in all of these things.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: try to use `$('#form_id').serialize()`.

Comment: @Ghost,thanks for the quick idea. Can you please show/teach me step by step how to do that?

Comment: you can also use jquery form plugin to send all info of a form trough ajax to the form action page

Comment: another possibility would be ` document.getElementsByTagName("checkbox")` if checkbox is a tagname

Comment: @klaudia try to use lolka's way below, load the serialized form values into `data:` in jquery. then in PHP call your POST values as you normally would do. if you want to make sure use `print_r($_POST);` so that you can debug and can expect what to process in POST.

Answer (score 1):

You are using your `product_name` as a string, not as a variable:

Try this:

```
data: 'product_name='+product_name+'&product_size='+product_size,
```

Or, as Ghost sad in comments, use formdata.

```
var dataString = $('form').serialize();
```

and later, in the ajax:

```
data: dataString,
...
```

Comment: Actually I still have no idea how this form serialize will work. As  you can see, what I send from the checkbox is the related input of it, not the value of the checkbox itself,means that if there are three checkbox (looping), then there would be three input for `name="items['.$i.']"` and `name="size['.$i.']"`.

Comment: You can read about this form serialization here: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ It's make a string like as you wish, but you can use the first solution of mine also.

Comment: I have read that, and in the example it only send the value of the checkbox itself, not the input related to the checkbox.

Comment: `document.getElementById('product_name').value;` is do the same. Get the value of the checkbox. How do you mean, the "input related"? Anyway, this form serialize is sending **all** the data from your form.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this...**

```
 <script>
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../actions/selectReferenceOrder.php",        
        data: "{'product_name':" + product_name + ", 'product_size':" + product_size+ "}",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html"
        success:function(html)
        {
            document.getElementById('outputReference').innerHTML = html;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain it to me first what it is doing with this and what is the difference with what I have?

Comment: data: product_name='+product_name+'&product_size ='+product_size ,This code have error

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

Ajax is simplified [check here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

```
var data = $('form').serialize();

 $.post( "../actions/selectReferenceOrder.php", { name: data}).done(function( data ) {
        alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
      });
```

**OR**

```
$.post( "../actions/selectReferenceOrder.php", { product_name: product_name, product_size : product_size  }).done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
```